# What is the time complexity of recursion func(int a, int n) and return a*func (a, n-1)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
int func(int a, int n){

     if (n==0) return 1;

     else return a*func(a,n-1);

}
```

Im learning algorithms and i want to know what is the time complexity of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function calculates `a^n`.

This function will be pushed for `n` number of time on the system stack (assigned to the program) with different parameter.

Therefore, time complexity is O(n).

If recursion is tough for you to visualize, then consider it analogous to  calculating using a loop. The loop will run for `n` number of times.

For example:

```
function power(a, n){    
    ans = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n;i++){
        ans = ans * a;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

**Best way to visualize recursion:**

Draw the recursion tree.